# Android-PullToRefresh frezzes ExpandableListView when refreshing

Tags: android, github, expandablelistview, pull-to-refresh

I am trying to integrate [Android-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) to refresh an ExpandableListView data. but it freezes UI until it I get data from Network and call method "onRefreshComplete()". I am calling webservice in AsyncTask's doInBackground and updating in onPostExecute.

I also tried to [download apk file](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handmark.pulltorefresh.samples), it refreshes ListView correctly but it also gets hang when refreshing ExpandableListView. It seems there is some issue at library itself. I have been trying to solve it for few hours but not able to figure it out. Any help will be appreciated.

Is there any other library that mimics PullToRefresh functionality for ExpandaleListView.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what could be wrong without seeing the code. But I have two thoughts:

1) The library you're using is deprecated. Have you tried using this one instead, [ActionBar-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh)
2) Are you doing any work on the UI thread when the refresh occurs?

I have used Android-PullToRefresh in a project recently. You can have a look at how I solved it here: https://github.com/slidese/SGU

Comment: Check their sample app.. It refreshes Listview without freeze but UI gets freezed when they do the same with ExpandableListView.

Comment: Sorry, I got the wrong link. Check this library instead: ActionBar-PullToRefresh

Comment: But it doesn't support ExpandableListView.